Issues with Implementing Adaptive Step-Size Explicit Runge-Kutta Methods in C for ODE Solvers
Background:
I am working on implementing a general adaptive step-size explicit Runge-Kutta (RK) solver in C for solving systems of ordinary differential equations (ODEs). My implementation is based in the theory presented in the book “Solving Ordinary Differential Equations I - Nonstiff Problems” by Hairer, Norsett, and Wanner, as well as the Python solve_ivp implementation in SciPy.
The main functionality of the solver should include:

Dynamically adjusting the time step size based on error estimation.
Using the same error norm check and step adjustment logic as solve_ivp (both the absolute and relative tolerances are considered in an RMS error norm).

I have tested my code on a Duffing oscillator system applying the Dormand-Prince RK5(4) method and compared the results to solve_ivp using identical system parameters and tolerances.
Problem Description:
While my implementation runs without crashing, it produces a different solution when compared to the one produced by python code (using SciPy's solve_ivp method). This behavior persists even when the ODE system and parameters are identical to a case where solve_ivp handles the problem efficiently and successfully.
Main Details:

Error Norm Calculation: My error norm computation is:
$$
err = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\text{dim}}\sum_{i=0}^{\text{dim} - 1}\left( \frac{|x_{{n+1}_i} - x_{{n+1}_i}^*|}{\text{atol} + \max(|x_{{n+1}_i}|, |x_{{n}_i}|) \cdot \text{rtol}} \right)^2}
$$

This matches the algorithm described in the literature and solve_ivp.

I am using the Dormand-Prince RK5(4) coefficients from Hairer et al., ensuring consistency between the main solution (b) and the embedded error estimator (b*).
The step size adjustment uses the factor $\text{factor} = \min(\text{max_factor}, \text{safety_factor} \cdot \text{err}^{-1/(q+1)})$ when accepted, and the factor $\text{factor} = \max(\text{min_factor}, \text{safety_factor} \cdot \text{err}^{-1/(q+1)})$, where q is the lowest method’s order of accuracy, min_factor is the  max_factor is maximum allowed increase in stepsize. I apply this factor to the current step size and enforce bounds using min_factor and max_factor. This implementation is exactly the same as in solve_ivp from SciPy.

C Code for reproduction:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SAFETY_FACTOR 0.9 // safety factor for the error be accepted in the next loop with high probability
#define MIN_FACTOR 0.2    // minimum allowed decrease in stepsize
#define MAX_FACTOR 10.0   // maximum allowed increase in stepsize (as suggested in reference: values between 1.5 and 5.0, scipy: 10)

typedef struct {
    int dim;    // system dimension
    double *x;  // system state variables
    double *p;  // system parameters
} SystemState;

typedef struct {
    double t;       // current time
    double t0;      // initial time
    double tf;      // final time
    double *dt;     // time increment
    double max_dt;  // maximum allowed stepsize
    double min_dt;  // minimum allowed stepsize 
    double atol;    // absolute tolerance of method
    double rtol;    // relative tolerance of method
} TimeState;

typedef struct {
    uint8_t s;           // number of stages of method
    double **A;          // matrix A (size s x s) - intermediate slopes weights
    double *b;           // vector b (size s) - solution weights for main approximation
    double *c;           // vector c (size s) - time weights 
    double *b_star;      // vector b* (size s) - solution weights for error estimation (optional)
    uint8_t q;           // lowest order of the method 
} ButcherTableau;

void **alloc_2D_array(int rows, int columns, size_t element_size) {
    void** array = malloc(rows * sizeof(void*));
    if (array == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed for rows in 'allocate_2D_array()' function.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        array[i] = malloc(columns * element_size);
        if (array[i] == NULL) {
            printf("Memory allocation failed for columns in 'allocate_2D_array()' function.\n");
            // Free the memory allocated for rows before returning NULL
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                free(array[j]);
            }
            free(array);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    
    return array;
}

void free_2D_mem(void **array_2D, int nrows) {
    // Safety check
    if (array_2D == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    // Free memory for each string in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
        if (array_2D[i] != NULL) {
            free(array_2D[i]);
        }
    }
    // Free memory for the array itself
    free(array_2D);
}

ButcherTableau initialize_butcher_tableau(uint8_t s, double A[s][s], double b[s], double c[s], double b_star[s], uint8_t q) {
    // Allocate memory
    ButcherTableau table;
    table.A = (double **)alloc_2D_array(s, s, sizeof(double));
    table.b = malloc(s * sizeof(table.b));
    table.c = malloc(s * sizeof(table.c));
    if (b_star != NULL) {
        table.b_star = malloc(s * sizeof(table.b_star));
    }
    // Fill structure with values
    table.s = s;
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        // Fill A
        for (int j = 0; j < s; j++){
            table.A[i][j] = A[i][j];
        }
        // Fill b and c
        table.b[i] = b[i];
        table.c[i] = c[i];
        // Fill b* if present
        if (b_star != NULL) {
            table.b_star[i] = b_star[i];
        }
    }
    if (q != 0) {
        table.q = q;
    }

    return table;
}

void free_butcher_tableau(ButcherTableau *table) {
    // Safety check
    if (table == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    if (table->A != NULL) {
        free_2D_mem((void**)table->A, table->s);
        table->A = NULL;
    }
    if (table->b != NULL) {
        free(table->b);
        table->b = NULL;
    }
    if (table->c != NULL) {
        free(table->c);
        table->c = NULL;
    }
    if (table->b_star != NULL) {
        free(table->b_star);
        table->b_star = NULL;
    }
}

ButcherTableau dormand_prince_rk54_adaptive(void) {
    // Define lowest order of the method
    uint8_t q = 4;
    // Define number of stages
    int s = 7;
    // Define Matrix A and vectors b and c
    double A[7][7] = {
        {            0.0,             0.0,            0.0,          0.0,             0.0,       0.0, 0.0},
        {        1.0/5.0,             0.0,            0.0,          0.0,             0.0,       0.0, 0.0},
        {       3.0/40.0,        9.0/40.0,            0.0,          0.0,             0.0,       0.0, 0.0},
        {      44.0/45.0,      -56.0/15.0,       32.0/9.0,          0.0,             0.0,       0.0, 0.0},
        { 19372.0/6561.0, -25360.0/2187.0, 64448.0/6561.0, -212.0/729.0,             0.0,       0.0, 0.0},
        {  9017.0/3168.0,     -355.0/33.0, 46732.0/5247.0,   49.0/176.0, -5103.0/18656.0,       0.0, 0.0},
        {     35.0/384.0,             0.0,   500.0/1113.0,  125.0/192.0,  -2187.0/6784.0, 11.0/84.0, 0.0},
    };
    double b[7] = {35.0/384.0, 0.0, 500.0/1113.0, 125.0/192.0, -2187.0/6784.0, 11.0/84.0, 0.0};
    double c[7] = {0.0, 1.0/5.0, 3.0/10.0, 4.0/5.0, 8.0/9.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    double b_star[7] = {5179.0/57600.0, 0.0, 7571.0/16695.0, 393.0/640.0, -92097.0/339200.0, 187.0/2100.0, 1.0/40.0};

    ButcherTableau table = initialize_butcher_tableau(s, A, b, c, b_star, q);

    return table;
}

void error(void) {
    printf("Error: Wrong dimension allocated for the system of equations.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void duffing(int dim, double *x, double *p, double t, double *f) {
    if (dim == 2) {
        f[0] = x[1];
        f[1] = p[1]*sin(p[0] * t) - 2*p[2]*x[1] - p[3]*x[0] - p[4]*x[0]*x[0]*x[0];    
    }
    else {
        error();
    }    
}

double RMS_norm_error(int dim, double *x_main, double *x_star, double *x, double rtol, double atol) {
    /*    
        Function input parameters:
        - dim: dimension of the ODE system
        - *x_main: main solution of the next step (the one estimated by vector b)
        - *x_star: solution for comparison (the one estimated by vector b_star)
        - *x: solution of the previous step
        - rtol: relative tolerance for the error computation
        - atol: absolute tolerance for the error computation 
    */
    double e = 0.0; double scale[dim];
    double error_norm;
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        scale[i] = (atol + fmax(fabs(x[i]), fabs(x_main[i]))*rtol);        
        e += pow((x_main[i] - x_star[i])/scale[i], 2);
    }
    error_norm = sqrt((1.0/(double)dim) * e);

    return error_norm;
}

void accept_or_reject_new_timestep(double *dt, double *factor, bool *step_rejected, bool *step_accepted, double error_norm, double error_exponent) {
    // Check for error norm value
    if (error_norm < 1.0) {
        // Check if error norm is null
        if (error_norm == 0.0) {
            // If error norm is null, define the factor as the maximum allowed increase in stepsize
            (*factor) = MAX_FACTOR;
        }
        else {
            // Take the maximum allowed increase factor, or the new factor based on the optimal step size
            (*factor) = fmin(MAX_FACTOR, SAFETY_FACTOR*pow(error_norm, error_exponent));
        }
        // Check if previous step was rejected
        if ((*step_rejected) == true) {
            // Change factor to 1 or below to prevent the step size from increasing after a rejection. This ensures stability in subsequent step size adjustments (as suggested by Shampine & Watts, 1979)
            (*factor) = fmin(1.0, (*factor));
        }
        // Update and accept new stepsize
        (*dt) *= (*factor);
        (*step_accepted) = true; 
        printf("accepted | error_norm = %f | dt = %f | factor = %f\n", error_norm, (*dt), (*factor));
    }
    else {
        // Reject and update stepsize based on minimum allowable decrease in stepsize
        (*factor) = fmax(MIN_FACTOR, SAFETY_FACTOR*pow(error_norm, error_exponent));
        (*dt) *= (*factor);
        (*step_rejected) = true;
        printf("rejected | error_norm = %f | dt = %f | factor = %f\n", error_norm, (*dt), (*factor));            
    }
}

void rk_adaptive_step(ButcherTableau *method, SystemState *s_state, TimeState *t_state, void (*odesys)(int, double *, double *, double, double *)) {
    // Define new variables for better readability
    int dim = s_state->dim;
    double *x = s_state->x;
    double *p = s_state->p;
    double t = t_state->t;
    double dt = (*t_state->dt);
    //double min_dt = t_state->min_dt;
    //double max_dt = t_state->max_dt;
    double atol = t_state->atol;
    double rtol = t_state->rtol;
    uint8_t s = method->s;
    double **A = method->A;
    double *b = method->b;
    double *c = method->c;
    double *b_star = method->b_star;
    uint8_t q = method->q;
    // Define array for temporary storage of the intermediary values of x[dim]
    double tmp[dim];
    // Define arrays for temporary storage of solution for comparison and solution candidate
    double x_main[dim]; double x_star[dim];
    // Define variables and arrays for error norm computation
    double error_norm; 
    double error_exponent = -1.0/((double)q + 1.0);
    // Define factor for multiplying the current step for obtaining the new stepsize
    double factor = 0.0;   
    // Define and initialize an array to store the slopes of each stage
    double k[s][dim];
    // Define control variables to allow or not allow stepsize
    bool step_accepted = false;
    bool step_rejected = false;
    // Compute solution approximation until accept the stepsize
    while (step_accepted == false) {
        // Compute 1st slope
        odesys(dim, x, p, t, k[0]);
        // Compute temporary values of x and remaining slopes (from k[1] to k[s-1])
        for (uint8_t i = 1; i < s; i++) {      // Loop for stages of k
            for (int m = 0; m < dim; m++) {     // Loop for the dimension of the x
                // Define temporary value of x
                tmp[m] = x[m];
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {    
                    tmp[m] += dt * A[i][j] * k[j][m];
                }
            }
            // Compute slope k[i] at time t + c[i]*dt
            odesys(dim, tmp, p, t + c[i]*dt, k[i]);
        }
        // Compute next system state candidate and comparison solution (of p+1 or p-1 order)
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
            x_main[i] = x[i];
            x_star[i] = x[i];
            for (uint8_t j = 0; j < s; j++) {
                x_main[i] += dt * b[j] * k[j][i];
                x_star[i] += dt * b_star[j] * k[j][i];
            }
        }
        // Compute error norm (in this case max norm is chosen instead of euclidean norm for speed reasons)
        error_norm = RMS_norm_error(dim, x_main, x_star, x, rtol, atol);
        // Check for error norm value to accept or reject new stepsize 
        accept_or_reject_new_timestep(&dt, &factor, &step_rejected, &step_accepted, error_norm, error_exponent);
    }
    // Check if current time is bigger than final time
    if ((t_state->t) + dt > t_state->tf){
        // if is bigger, reduce the stepsize to match the size to obtain the final step
        dt = (t_state->tf - t_state->t);          
    }
    // Compute next system and time states
    (*t_state->dt) = dt;
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++){
        s_state->x[i] = x_main[i];
    }
}

void write_results(FILE *output_file, int dim, double t, double *x, int mode) {
    // Check the mode of the function
    if (mode == 0) {
        fprintf(output_file, "Time ");
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
            fprintf(output_file, "x[%i] ", i);
        }
        fprintf(output_file, "\n");
    }
    else if (mode == 1) {
        // Header
        fprintf(output_file, "Time ");
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
            fprintf(output_file, "x[%i] ", i);
        }
        fprintf(output_file, "\n");
        // Initial Conditions
        fprintf(output_file, "%.10f ", t);
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
            fprintf(output_file, "%.10lf ", x[i]);
        }
        fprintf(output_file, "\n");
    } 
    else if (mode == 2) {
        fprintf(output_file, "%.10f ", t);
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
            fprintf(output_file, "%.10lf ", x[i]);
        }
        fprintf(output_file, "\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Failed to write results in output file using mode (%d)...\n", mode);
        return;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    // Program Parameters
    double tf = 10.0;
    double dt = 9.999999999999999e-05;
    // System Parameters
    double p[5] = { 1.6, 0.2, 0.025, -0.5, 0.5 };
    int dim = 2;
    double *x = malloc(dim * sizeof(*x));
    // Initial Conditions
    double t0 = 0.0;
    x[0] = -1.0; x[1] = 0.0;
    double t = t0;
    // Define states 
    SystemState s_state = {dim, x, p};
    double max_dt = 0.0;   
    double min_dt = 0.0;    
    double atol = 1e-6;    
    double rtol = 1e-3;    
    TimeState t_state = {t, t0, tf, &dt, max_dt, min_dt, atol, rtol};
    // Create output files to store results, create header and print initial conditions
    FILE *out = fopen("output_adaptive_rk.csv", "w");
    write_results(out, dim, t0, x, 1);
    // Initialize solver tableau
    ButcherTableau solver_table = dormand_prince_rk54_adaptive();
    // Call numerical integrator
    while (t_state.t < tf) {
        rk_adaptive_step(&solver_table, &s_state, &t_state, duffing);
        // Update time
        t_state.t += (*t_state.dt);         
        // write results of the integration
        write_results(out, s_state.dim, t_state.t, s_state.x, 2);
    }
    // Close output file and free allocated memory
    fclose(out);
    free(s_state.x);
    free_butcher_tableau(&solver_table);
    return 0;
}

Working Python code using SciPy Library
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def duffing(t, x, p):
    f = np.zeros(len(x))

    f[0] = x[1]
    f[1] = p[1]*np.sin(p[0]*t) - 2*p[2]*x[1] - p[3]*x[0] - p[4]*(x[0]**3)

    return f

# System and Input Information
system = duffing
dimension = 2
filepath = "output_python.csv"
savedata = True
savefig = False

# System Parameters
Omega = 1.6
gamma = 0.2
zeta = 0.025
alpha = -0.5
beta = 0.5
# Create List with parameters
p = np.array([Omega, gamma,  zeta,  alpha, beta])
tf = 10
solver = 'RK45'

# Simulation Parameters
x0 = np.array([-1.0, 0.0])
tspan = np.array([0.0, tf])
hmax = 10000

# Solution                                                               
sol = solve_ivp(system, tspan, x0, method = solver, max_step = hmax,  args = (p,))

t = sol.t
x = sol.y

print(f"Integration: {sol.success}")
print(f"Integration message: {sol.message}")

# Save Solution in a file                                                 
if savedata == True:
    # Make header
    header = "Time"
    for i in range(dimension):
        header = header + f" x[{i}]"
    # Prepare the data for writing
    data = np.vstack((t, x)).T
    # Write solution in file
    with open(filepath, 'w') as file:
        # Write the header row
        file.write(f'{header}\n')    
        # Write the data rows
        for row in data:
            file.write(' '.join(f"{element:.10f}" for element in row) + '\n')


Question:
The solve_ivp method from SciPy uses the same stepsize control scheme (with some added functionalities for dense output - although I think it does not interfere with the stepsize control), and it solves the system with no problem.
What could be causing my implementation to present a different behavior of the SciPy's python implementation, despite an error norm that appears to be properly computed? Are there subtle numerical issues or implementation pitfalls I might be overlooking that would explain this behavior?
Any insights or debugging tips would be greatly appreciated!
EDIT 1:
I updted the code with the modifications proposed by @Steven Roberts and it now finishes the computation successfully, however results in a wrong solution.
Specifically, the modifications were made and wrapped in the function void accept_or_reject_new_timestep(...)
When I test the code with fixed timestep without calling void accept_or_reject_new_timestep(...) it provides a very similar solution when compared to the python one. So probably the problem still lies within this function, but I could not identify it.
EDIT 2:
I fixed the typo errors in the allocation of double *x and in the butcher tableau of the method.
I also modified the code to handle the initial time and final times correctly.
I also did an extensive search for the error using clang debugger and still couldn't find the problem.
Here is the comparison between the C code solution (with the modifications suggested by @Steven Roberts and the python code solution).

“Additionally, below are the first 10 iterations, along with the corresponding plots of the solution for each code.”
C Code:
        Time          x[0]         x[1] 
0.0000000000 -1.0000000000 0.0000000000 
0.0010000000 -1.0000000000 0.0000000016 
0.0110000000 -0.9999999998 0.0000004816 
0.1110000000 -0.9999997657 0.0000516630 
0.6813148727 -0.9997664356 0.0051223127 
1.5389817616 -0.9668827420 0.1070958444 
2.2696064099 -0.8829198300 0.0416311582 
3.1441907357 -0.9177919403 -0.1461982124 
3.9700809285 -1.1022036152 -0.2134620613 
4.8628372946 -1.1823694583 0.0598695152 

Python Code
        Time          x[0]         x[1]
0.0000000000 -1.0000000000 0.0000000000
0.0001000000 -1.0000000000 0.0000000016
0.0011000000 -0.9999999999 0.0000001936
0.0111000000 -0.9999999271 0.0000197092
0.1111000000 -0.9999271242 0.0019640488
0.7828770943 -0.9773192706 0.0801597819
1.8665903212 -0.8235328764 0.1515719181
2.9213148445 -0.7895473986 -0.1317990583
3.9760393677 -1.0695148343 -0.3178486841
4.9749144004 -1.2317614576 0.0610837101


EDIT 3:
I performed some tests and I think the problem lies in the calculation of the norm error. This can be seen the following results, which lists, for each iteration, if step was accepted or not, the error norm, the stepsize and the factor which the old stepsize is multiplied to estimate the new stepsize:
Results of Python code (18 iterations):
accepted | error_norm = 0.000000 | dt = 0.001000 | factor = 10.000000
accepted | error_norm = 0.000000 | dt = 0.010000 | factor = 10.000000
accepted | error_norm = 0.000000 | dt = 0.100000 | factor = 10.000000
accepted | error_norm = 0.000043 | dt = 0.671777 | factor = 6.717771
accepted | error_norm = 0.054046 | dt = 1.083713 | factor = 1.613204
accepted | error_norm = 0.386792 | dt = 1.179401 | factor = 1.088296
rejected | error_norm = 1.032345 | dt = 1.054725 | factor = 0.894288
accepted | error_norm = 0.489627 | dt = 1.054725 | factor = 1.000000
accepted | error_norm = 0.775090 | dt = 0.998875 | factor = 0.947048
accepted | error_norm = 0.667836 | dt = 0.974585 | factor = 0.975682
rejected | error_norm = 1.277779 | dt = 0.835163 | factor = 0.856942
accepted | error_norm = 0.745202 | dt = 0.797184 | factor = 0.954526
accepted | error_norm = 0.415525 | dt = 0.855228 | factor = 1.072811
accepted | error_norm = 0.163471 | dt = 1.105697 | factor = 1.292869
accepted | error_norm = 0.382128 | dt = 1.206249 | factor = 1.090940
rejected | error_norm = 1.959225 | dt = 0.948992 | factor = 0.786730
accepted | error_norm = 0.517679 | dt = 0.948992 | factor = 1.000000
accepted | error_norm = 0.118478 | dt = 0.665735 | factor = 1.378843

Results of the C Code (17 iterations):
accepted | error_norm = 0.000000 | dt = 0.001000 | factor = 10.000000
accepted | error_norm = 0.000000 | dt = 0.010000 | factor = 10.000000
accepted | error_norm = 0.000000 | dt = 0.100000 | factor = 10.000000
accepted | error_norm = 0.000054 | dt = 0.641604 | factor = 6.416042
accepted | error_norm = 0.078469 | dt = 0.960660 | factor = 1.497279
rejected | error_norm = 1.204689 | dt = 0.832985 | factor = 0.867097
accepted | error_norm = 0.508293 | dt = 0.832985 | factor = 1.000000
accepted | error_norm = 0.325256 | dt = 0.938501 | factor = 1.126672
accepted | error_norm = 0.462392 | dt = 0.985543 | factor = 1.050124
accepted | error_norm = 0.639383 | dt = 0.969987 | factor = 0.984216
rejected | error_norm = 1.681057 | dt = 0.786850 | factor = 0.811196
accepted | error_norm = 0.553947 | dt = 0.786850 | factor = 1.000000
accepted | error_norm = 0.046281 | dt = 1.309344 | factor = 1.664034
rejected | error_norm = 2.513436 | dt = 0.980038 | factor = 0.748495
accepted | error_norm = 0.233035 | dt = 0.980038 | factor = 1.000000
accepted | error_norm = 0.476945 | dt = 1.022803 | factor = 1.043636
accepted | error_norm = 0.931426 | dt = 0.933694 | factor = 0.912878

However, I could not identify any differences in how the python calculates the norm when compared to my implementation. Below is the 'SciPy' implementation of the method. Am I missing something?
# Multiply steps computed from asymptotic behaviour of errors by this.
SAFETY = 0.9

MIN_FACTOR = 0.2  # Minimum allowed decrease in a step size.
MAX_FACTOR = 10  # Maximum allowed increase in a step size.


def rk_step(fun, t, y, f, h, A, B, C, K):
    """Perform a single Runge-Kutta step.

    This function computes a prediction of an explicit Runge-Kutta method and
    also estimates the error of a less accurate method.

    Notation for Butcher tableau is as in [1]_.

    Parameters
    ----------
    fun : callable
        Right-hand side of the system.
    t : float
        Current time.
    y : ndarray, shape (n,)
        Current state.
    f : ndarray, shape (n,)
        Current value of the derivative, i.e., ``fun(x, y)``.
    h : float
        Step to use.
    A : ndarray, shape (n_stages, n_stages)
        Coefficients for combining previous RK stages to compute the next
        stage. For explicit methods the coefficients at and above the main
        diagonal are zeros.
    B : ndarray, shape (n_stages,)
        Coefficients for combining RK stages for computing the final
        prediction.
    C : ndarray, shape (n_stages,)
        Coefficients for incrementing time for consecutive RK stages.
        The value for the first stage is always zero.
    K : ndarray, shape (n_stages + 1, n)
        Storage array for putting RK stages here. Stages are stored in rows.
        The last row is a linear combination of the previous rows with
        coefficients

    Returns
    -------
    y_new : ndarray, shape (n,)
        Solution at t + h computed with a higher accuracy.
    f_new : ndarray, shape (n,)
        Derivative ``fun(t + h, y_new)``.

    References
    ----------
    .. [1] E. Hairer, S. P. Norsett G. Wanner, "Solving Ordinary Differential
           Equations I: Nonstiff Problems", Sec. II.4.
    """
    K[0] = f
    for s, (a, c) in enumerate(zip(A[1:], C[1:]), start=1):
        dy = np.dot(K[:s].T, a[:s]) * h
        K[s] = fun(t + c * h, y + dy)

    y_new = y + h * np.dot(K[:-1].T, B)
    f_new = fun(t + h, y_new)

    K[-1] = f_new

    return y_new, f_new


class RungeKutta(OdeSolver):
    """Base class for explicit Runge-Kutta methods."""
    C: np.ndarray = NotImplemented
    A: np.ndarray = NotImplemented
    B: np.ndarray = NotImplemented
    E: np.ndarray = NotImplemented
    P: np.ndarray = NotImplemented
    order: int = NotImplemented
    error_estimator_order: int = NotImplemented
    n_stages: int = NotImplemented

    def __init__(self, fun, t0, y0, t_bound, max_step=np.inf,
                 rtol=1e-3, atol=1e-6, vectorized=False,
                 first_step=None, **extraneous):
        warn_extraneous(extraneous)
        super().__init__(fun, t0, y0, t_bound, vectorized,
                         support_complex=True)
        self.y_old = None
        self.max_step = validate_max_step(max_step)
        self.rtol, self.atol = validate_tol(rtol, atol, self.n)
        self.f = self.fun(self.t, self.y)
        if first_step is None:
            self.h_abs = select_initial_step(
                self.fun, self.t, self.y, t_bound, max_step, self.f, self.direction,
                self.error_estimator_order, self.rtol, self.atol)
        else:
            self.h_abs = validate_first_step(first_step, t0, t_bound)
        self.K = np.empty((self.n_stages + 1, self.n), dtype=self.y.dtype)
        self.error_exponent = -1 / (self.error_estimator_order + 1)
        self.h_previous = None

    def _estimate_error(self, K, h):
        return np.dot(K.T, self.E) * h

    def _estimate_error_norm(self, K, h, scale):
        return norm(self._estimate_error(K, h) / scale)

    def _step_impl(self):
        t = self.t
        y = self.y

        max_step = self.max_step
        rtol = self.rtol
        atol = self.atol

        min_step = 10 * np.abs(np.nextafter(t, self.direction * np.inf) - t)

        if self.h_abs > max_step:
            h_abs = max_step
        elif self.h_abs < min_step:
            h_abs = min_step
        else:
            h_abs = self.h_abs

        step_accepted = False
        step_rejected = False

        while not step_accepted:
            if h_abs < min_step:
                return False, self.TOO_SMALL_STEP

            h = h_abs * self.direction
            t_new = t + h

            if self.direction * (t_new - self.t_bound) > 0:
                t_new = self.t_bound

            h = t_new - t
            h_abs = np.abs(h)

            y_new, f_new = rk_step(self.fun, t, y, self.f, h, self.A,
                                   self.B, self.C, self.K)
            scale = atol + np.maximum(np.abs(y), np.abs(y_new)) * rtol
            error_norm = self._estimate_error_norm(self.K, h, scale)

            if error_norm < 1:
                if error_norm == 0:
                    factor = MAX_FACTOR
                else:
                    factor = min(MAX_FACTOR,
                                 SAFETY * error_norm ** self.error_exponent)

                if step_rejected:
                    factor = min(1, factor)

                h_abs *= factor

                step_accepted = True
            else:
                h_abs *= max(MIN_FACTOR,
                             SAFETY * error_norm ** self.error_exponent)
                step_rejected = True

        self.h_previous = h
        self.y_old = y

        self.t = t_new
        self.y = y_new

        self.h_abs = h_abs
        self.f = f_new

        return True, None

    def _dense_output_impl(self):
        Q = self.K.T.dot(self.P)
        return RkDenseOutput(self.t_old, self.t, self.y_old, Q)


Welcome to SciComp.SE.  Your interest in writing an ODE solver is appreciated.  However the post itself could be improved, as the evident goal of comparing your effort to the solve_ivp method opens up a lot of ground.  Debugging help here is premised on a minimal complete verifiable example (aka MRE in current parlance).  It would help Readers (now and in the future) if your post could be pared down to bare bones, and doing so might well lead to finding the cause yourself.

First thing to do is to check that you have a convergent scheme when using a fixed time step. Compute a qusi exact solution for your system with solve_ivp, and see if your scheme converges to this solution as the steps decreased.

Hello @Laurent90, I verified convergence using the classic 4th-order Runge-Kutta method and the Dormand-Prince 4(5) method from solve_ivp. Both methods converged to the same solution as the step size decreased.

But you should also check with your actual RK45 scheme, both main and embedded schemes (error estimate).

Notice how the error_norm does not change after a rejected step. This is because the time step is not being updated correctly. It is initially written to the local double dt, but updates are written to (*t_state->dt). When retrying a rejected step, dt becomes stale; it does not get updated. The fix is to update dt manually, make it a pointer to t_state->dt, or just use (*t_state->dt) everywhere and remove dt.
There may be more issues, but that's what I could see initially on mobile without running the code. I would suggest using a debugger like GDB to step through the code to help investigate issues like this.
EDIT:
Now that I can run the code, a few more issues:

double *x = malloc(dim* sizeof(x)); -> double *x = malloc(dim* sizeof(*x));
The third row of $A$ coefficients is wrong. {3./40., 9.0/40.0, ...}
The time step loop starts and ends at the wrong time.

for (t_state.t = t0; t_state.t < tf; t_state.t = t_state.t + (*t_state.dt)) {


Thank you, Steven. Indeed the dt was not being updated. I modified and tested the code and now at least it successfully end the simulation. However it results in a wrong solution. I'll edit the question to reflect the updates on the code.

See the edit. Most of these issues can be found with the help of a debugger and double checking the coefficients.

Thank you again, Steven. I was able to fix the issues, but the solution is still incorrect. I performed an extensive check using the debugger and made adjustments to some parts of the code, but I still couldn’t identify the error. I’ve updated the post with new information. In the meantime, I’ll continue investigating.

You will have this effect if first the error in each step is quite large, or the allowed error is very small, forcing a rather small step size, and then rounding errors in each step are so large compared to the allowed error, that the step size is made even smaller. Which doesn’t help because your error is mostly rounding error which doesn’t shrink with the step size.

I don't see why rounding errors would be significant here. The local errors are on the order of 1e-3 (reltol) while rounding errors are on the order of 1e-16. If you replace all the doubles in the code with float, the difference is on the order of 1e-7 which indicates roundoff error is not dominant.
